# Could not find or load main class - Under unusual circumstances

Tags: java, compilation, runtime, java-compiler-api

Alright, I know this is a very common, very simple question, but mine comes with rather unusual circumstances. (Circumstances which I was unable to find a solution to elsewhere on the internet.) So, I have some source code which I am programmatically compiling via `JavaCompiler`. I then attempt to execute the compiled code with Runtime. (That is, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[])`.) However, when I attempt to execute said code, I get `Could not find or load main class.` The source code in question follows this base-model:

```
package compiledCode;
public class Compiled
{
    public Compiled(){}
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello!! ;D");
    }
}
```

Even that code won't execute. I still get the same error. Thanks in advance for your help. :)

*Edit:
The steps I take in detail are as follows:

1. I start with the code mentioned above in a String called code. I then make a File object (in this case, Compiled.java.)
2. I use a custom method of mine which I have tested and have ensured it works to compile the file (and optionally get a Class object from it, though, for specific reasons, I can't do it that way for this.) into a .class file. (Using the `JavaCompiler` API.)
3. I then use `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(new String[]{"java",[location of .class file]});` to execute it.

It is at this point that I get an error.

The exact code I am using, as requested, is this..

```
ClassFileHelper.toClass(src, "C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/ /Eclipse/Workspace/RoccedGame/ServiceCoder", "ServiceCoder");
System.out.println("java "+src.getAbsolutePath().substring(0,src.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".java"))+".class");
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java",src.getAbsolutePath().substring(0,src.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".java"))+".class"});
```

The String manipulation in the 3rd line is a bit messy, but I've triple-checked to ensure that it works - which it does. If you would like to see the code for the .`toClass()` bit, go [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?0suzfoe5niwh6ae).

Comment: make sure you give the right path of generated .class file to the command.

Comment: are you sure ?? it running on my pc. :/

Comment: @steven-fontaine could you provide the exact steps how you're trying to run and compile the code...

Comment: to others, did you read the part in the question that this is about programmatic compilation?

Comment: @eis Sure.
I start with the code mentioned above in a String called `code`. I then make a File object (in this case, `Compiled.java`.) After that, I use a custom method of mine which I have tested and have ensured it works to compile the file (and optionally get a Class object from it, though, for specific reasons, I can't do it that way for this.) into a .class file. (Using the `JavaCompiler API`.) I then use `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(new String[]{"java",[location of .class file]});` to execute it. However, it never gets that far. It only gets to the last step in compiling (where in gets the..

Comment: .. Class object) and then it throws that error..

Comment: @StevenFontaine Better if you edit this information in your question. Its really hard to read as comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just got this error confused with another error I was having earlier. :P I was wrong about where the error occurs, it is thrown when it is executed. My bad. :P

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post a self-contained program that demonstrates the problem, along with the *exact* error messages, as well as a printout of the *exact* parameters to `Runtime.exec()`. Because as it is, you've given a description of what you *think* the steps are, but the parameters in step #3 don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @StevenFontaine  as parsifal said, [self-contained](http://sscce.org/) would be the crucial word here:)

Comment: @Steven Have you tried to run `java compiledCode.Compiled` from command line?

Comment: @tcb Yes, and I get the same error...? O.o I just now tried that.. Perhaps it's because I am compiling using the JavaCompiler API?

Comment: Try to compile using `javac`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the correct parameters to `Runtime.exec()`.

You pass the actual location of the compiled classfile. However, you should be passing a class name, and if your class is in a package you'll also need to pass the root of the package hierarchy as a `-classpath` parameter.

This is described in the JDK documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html